# How to say "Catch a plane"

Tags: grammar

I'm interested to see if there is a translation for "catch a plane". I know that 赶不上飞机 is an expression - but could you say

"今天我有很多事。 最要紧的是赶上飞机“

Comment: It sounds very natural to me.

Comment: Maybe you can try 接住飞机... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

赶飞机 is ok. you can also say 赶火车(train) or 赶车(car/bus) or 赶地铁(subway)

赶上飞机 is also correct, but it's long and a little bit strange in speaking.

you can say 今天我事情很多，还要赶飞机

Answer (score 2):

"To catch a plane" is being ready/in position to board a plane on time. I would say `赶上飞机` implies you're *rushing* to do so. Although it works fine normally, such as in your example sentence, it might sound a bit weird when you have plenty of time.

A more generic equivalent would be something like `搭飞机` or `准时搭上飞机`.